# What does the blue number next to "favorites" refer to?

Tags: support, user-interface, notifications, bookmarks

I don't understand notifications for favorites. I presume the number in blue that I see when I go to my profile is telling me that that many of my favorites have had something happen to them. But which ones?

For example, just now I had a blue 5 next to favorites, but when I click on it, two favorites have a yellow background (which I'm guessing means "something happened") and I couldn't see anything to indicate what else had happened.

What am I missing?

Comment: Here's a start: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53585/how-do-favorite-questions-work.

Comment: This is not a complete answer, but to see which favorited question had a change, sort your favorites tab by "activity" and that should prove helpful.

Answer (score 2):

[How do favorite questions work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53585/how-do-favorite-questions-work/53580#53580) (emphasis mine):

> - The favorites tab on your profile has a counter indicating how many of your favorite questions have changed since you last viewed that tab. When you click on the tab, recently changed questions will be highlighted. **"Changed" includes comments on or edits to the question and new or edited answers**. This is a way to get updates on questions that you yourself didn't ask.

The thing is we can't quickly know exactly what has changed; so there are some proposals going on. The following Meta SE post has more about it: [Detail Recent Favorite changes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83292/detail-recent-favorite-changes).